# Postgresql how to use set of inserted ids for inserting to another table?

Tags: postgresql

What I want: if record with the same unique(doctor_id, year, month) exists, we need to increase `sum` via input `sum` value.

I'm trying this SQL query:

```
with rows as (
    insert into mis_doctor_stats (doctor_id, year, month, sum)
        values (1, 2025, 3, 100),
               (1, 2021, 4, 6)
        on conflict (doctor_id, year, month) do update set sum = mis_doctor_stats.sum + excluded.sum
        returning id)
insert
into mis_doctor_stats_files(file_id, stats_id)
select 4, rows.id
from rows;
```

But still got the error: FROM expected, got ';'

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h88pA.png)

Comment: Strictly speaking, [`rows` is indeed a "non-reserved" keyword in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html), but you should still probably call your CTE something else, even just `cte` if you lack inspiration...

Answer (score 0):

As @Bruno strictly said the problem was in the `alias_name` for which I tried to use reserved keyword `rows`.

The right solution in my case:

```sql
with cte as (
    insert into mis_doctor_stats (doctor_id, year, month, sum)
        values (1, 2020, 3, 100),
               (1, 2023, 4, 6)
        on conflict (doctor_id, year, month) do update set sum = mis_doctor_stats.sum + excluded.sum
        returning id)
insert
into mis_doctor_stats_files(file_id, stats_id)
select 4, cte.id
from cte
on conflict do nothing;
```